# Stacked bar chart by group and subgroup in SAS

Tags: sas

I am unable to create stacked charts by group and subgroup in sas9.4, I want charts which are similar to excel graphs. Please find the sample data and excel graph below (first image) and also the SAS graph (second image).

I am unable to set the common year for the SEGMENT 'ACTUAL' AND 'FORECAST' on the same axis (year). The actual means the data has up to 2014 and forecast means after 2014, Both should fall in the same axis.

```
goptions reset=all ;
goptions colors=(red blue green);
legend1 label=none ;

proc gchart data=NEW;
vbar year/ discrete type=sum sumvar=VALUE 
  group= segment subgroup=WKSCOPE      ;
  where year le 2020 AND YEAR ge 2012;
run;
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve this with annotation.  I know `SGPLOT` better than `GCHART` so I'll answer it this way.

```
data have;
  input segment $ year wkscope $ value;
  datalines;
ACTUAL 2012 PH 5
ACTUAL 2012 PH 1
ACTUAL 2012 BHS 1
ACTUAL 2012 RES 2
ACTUAL 2013 PH 2
ACTUAL 2013 PH 5
ACTUAL 2013 BHS 1
ACTUAL 2014 RES 2
FORECAST 2015 PH 3
FORECAST 2015 BHS 0
FORECAST 2016 PH 4
FORECAST 2016 RES 1
FORECAST 2017 PH 5
FORECAST 2017 BHS 1
FORECAST 2017 RES 2
;;;;
run;

data sgannods;
  x1space='wallpercent';
  y1space='wallpercent';
  x1=75;
  y1=-10;
  label="Forecast";
  function='text';
  output;
  x1=25;
  label="Actual";
  output;
run;

proc sgplot data=have sganno=sgannods;
    vbar year/response=value group=wkscope groupdisplay=stack;
run;
```

Basically, do everything except segment, then annotate using that value.  You can generate it by hand like I do, or (preferably) generate it from the original data if it could change.  I use `WALLPERCENT` since it's going to be first half is actual last half is forecast, but if it could change (2 actual 4 forecast) then you shouldn't do that; you should either use `WALLPERCENT` and work out the proper position from the data (with a proc freq, probably) or use `DATAVALUE` and put it under the middle value.

If this isn't close enough, I would go to [robslink.com](http://robslink.com/), which has a nice set of examples (and is written by one of the developers of the GCHART set of procs).  Sanjay also has a blog, Graphically Speaking which has some great examples, and both post on [SAS Communities](http://communities.sas.com).

The image I produce follows here.  It's not particularly close in other manners but all of those are easy to fix (color scheme, sizes, location of legends).
[image]

Data labels are the one thing you can't really have this way; they're addable if you use `VBARPARM`, but that requires summarizing the data ahead of time.  Sanjay covers this in one of his [blog posts](http://blogs.sas.com/content/graphicallyspeaking/2014/08/24/new-graphics-features-in-sas-9-4m2-part-1/) about 9.4M2 (if you have the M2 maintenance release); I also cover this in my [MWSUG Paper, Labelling without the Hassle: How to Produce Labeled Stacked Bar Charts Using
SGPLOT and GTL Without Annotate](http://www.mwsug.org/proceedings/2014/DV/MWSUG-2014-DV04.pdf) if you have an older version.

Comment: Thanks Joe, One more thing I have to maintain RBG colours and labels

Comment: You can ask how to do that in another question if you need to, but it's fairly easy to google.